# What is the correct way to save post data (with integer and string values) in the database golang?

Tags: go, mgo, go-gin

I've the following golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("/save-address", SaveAddress)
    router.Run()
}

func SaveAddress(c *gin.Context){
    var err error
    conditions := bson.M{}
    c.Request.ParseForm()
    for key, _ := range c.Request.PostForm {
        if key != "id"{
            conditions[key] = c.PostForm(key)
        }
    }
    conditions["_id"] = 1
    mongoSession := ConnectDb()

    sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
    defer sessionCopy.Close()

    getCollection := mongoSession.DB("bformssettings").C("address")
    err = getCollection.Insert(conditions)
    if err != nil{
        println(err)
    }else{
        println("Data saved successfully!!!")
    }
}
func ConnectDb() (mongoSession *mgo.Session) {
    mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{"localhost:27017"},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: "bformssettings",
    }

    mongoSession, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateSession: %s\n", err)
    }

    mongoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    return mongoSession
}
```

When I run the code, data of the following format will be saved in the database:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "customer_id" : "3", "address" : "Chicago, IL", "city" : "Chicago", "state" : "IL", "zipcode" : "60647" }
```

**Problem:**

`customer_id` is an integer value, **but** it will be saved as string in the database.

**Possible workaround:**

It is possible to reconvert the string representation of `id` back to integer before saving it in the database.

**Question:**

Is there another way to save data as it is? E.g. to save integer values as integer values?

Comment: `c.PostForm(key)` - what type does this return?

Comment: This returns the string value, thats way it saved in string format.

Comment: So then it's not "data saved in database is incorrect with golang?" then :-) It's that you retrieve "incorrect" data in the very first place

Comment: @zerkms I have updated the question, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your saved document, you can see it's `_id` property is already a number (and not a string), so yes, this is definitely possible.

The reason why you end up with a `customer_id` property being of type `string` is because the document you save (`conditions` variable) holds a `string` value for `customer_id` property. And it is of type `string` because you filled it with the return value of [`Context.PostForm()`](http://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.PostForm) which returns a form value as a `string`.

If you want it to be an integer in the database, convert it to a Go integer before setting it in `conditions`. For that you may use [`strconv.Atoi()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) for example.

```
for key, _ := range c.Request.PostForm {
    value := c.PostForm(key)
    if key == "customer_id" {
        if id, err := strconv.Atoi(value); err != nil {
            // Not a valid number, handle error
        } else {
            conditions[key] = id
        }
    } else {
        if key != "id"{
            conditions[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

You have to define *somehow* which fields are supposed to hold integer values. I just showed a way to do that with a single field. If you have multiple of them, you may list them in a slice, and use a single `for` loop to detect / handle all; or even better, put them in a map that acts as a set, and you can detect these fields without a `for` loop.

Another option would be to create a `struct` type modeling your form input data, and use a library like [Gorilla's schema](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema) to unmarshal into that struct in a type-aware manner.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But if I have lets say 15 fields and 5 of them are integer then 5 time I need to add condition within the loop. That is not the correct way for me because my data supposed to be big during runtime. So Is there a another way to handle this in golang?